# Finding all entries that can be found by recursive selection

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I want to select all countries in Countries that can be found by recursively adding all neighbouring countries to the reachable countries already found by looking at the set that starts with just 'Sweden'. Basically, I have the set S which at the very beginning is the set {Sweden}, and select all names from the table `borders` that are equal to the Country1 attribute while the Country2 attribute is in S, or are equal to the Country2 attribute while the Country1 attribute is in S. I modify S to this selected set. Then I keep doing this selection until I find no new countries that aren't in S.

By performing the selection on the table

```
Country1      Country2
----------------------
Sweden        Finland
Norway        Sweden
Norway        Finland
Norway        Russia
Russia        Ukraine
Russia        Finland
Russia        China
Canada        United States
```

I should get the result:

```
Name
----------------------
Finland        
Norway        
Russia        
Ukraine       
China
```

It's not the best but I hope that you get the idea of what I want to do. I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: What is your DBMS ? Recursion is product specific

Comment: The selection requires the use of recursion, right?

Comment: Left justified SQL, so hard to read...

Comment: PostgreSQL supports Recursive CTE (common-table expressions). Show us some sample data and expected result and in 10 minutes somebody will write a working query.

Comment: Basically it tells you to select every Name from Country that is a neighbour to Sweden or a neighbour to a neighbour to Sweden and so on...

Comment: Yes, as the number of  neighbouring countries levels is unknown, you need a recursion.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+recursive-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of (edited)

```
create table borders(
    Country1 varchar(100),
    Country2 varchar(100)
);
insert into borders(Country1,Country2)
values
('Sweden','Finland'),
('Norway','Sweden'),
('Norway','Finland'),
('Norway','Russia'),
('Russia','Ukraine'),
('Russia','Finland'),
('Russia','China'),
('Canada','United States')
;

WITH RECURSIVE neighbours AS (
    -- start with 'Sweden' if any neighbour of it exists
    SELECT DISTINCT 'Sweden' as Name, ARRAY[cast('Sweden' as varchar)] as path
    FROM borders b 
    WHERE 'Sweden' IN (b.Country1, b.Country2)
    --
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      CASE WHEN nb.Name = b.Country1 THEN b.Country2 ELSE b.Country1 END, 
      path || CASE WHEN nb.Name = b.Country1 THEN b.Country2 ELSE b.Country1 END
    FROM borders b
    JOIN neighbours nb ON nb.Name IN(b.Country1, b.Country2) 
          AND NOT(b.Country1 = ANY(path) AND b.Country2 = ANY(path))
)
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM neighbours;
```

Comment: You helped me come up with a query which I believe solves the problem. Mine takes advantage of UNION (without ALL) instead of using flags.

Comment: Although I'm not sure your solution is correct (it doesn't work for me), it guided me in the right direction, eventually leading me to the solution I believe is correct. To mark this thread as solved, I am therefore marking your answer as the accepted answer.